# Facebook Scope Change From user to user

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I have created Facebook app to get the feeds and i am using java with [restfb](http://restfb.com/) to get the access token. I have specify scope for user post 'user_posts'.
The problem is when i login with my account i am able to get feeds but when i login from my friend account and accept the app permission i am not getting feeds.
I debug  them in in [facebook debuge tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) the user post_scope is not listed in my friend account token and its totally different from mine.
See following screen shots.
Access Token From My Account:
[image]

Access Token From My Friend Account
[image]
Can anyone tell me whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can only request extended permissions for other users than admins/developers/testers of your app if the app passed the Login Review process. It's all in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/best-practices#loginreview